# Volley request with HttpUrlConnection

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm just updated app with api 23 (Android Marshmallow) And MarshMallow removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or higher, have to use the HttpURLConnection class instead. but volley support only AndroidHttpClient.
So how can i use volley with HttpUrlConnection for better performance and caching requested data.

Comment: Please read line 54-56, it uses HttpUrlConnection   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/1a39583f0ee06329f7918ed9a4c7d0e7cd342917/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/Volley.java

Answer (score 1):

Go to Android SDK Dir ...Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\optional

Copy "org.apache.http.legacy.jar" file to lib folder. Clean project and run.

Comment: **sounds good!**
[see here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) but httpurlconnection peformace better and request time less then ApacheHttpClient.